# Apache SOLR and C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, solr

Am newbie to Apache SOLR 7.4. Am trying to upload XML file to remote server where the SOLR 7.4  is hosted.I need to update the collection with new XML file uploaded to the server. How can I re-index the collection ?
Things I have tried like using Simple Post Tool, CURL command with update etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a C# application, [using SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet) is the suggested way. To upload a file to Solr Cell (which is what the module that extracts content from most file types is called), you [can follow the example given in the manual](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Extract.md). To parse the file for content to see how it behaves with the file you've uploaded:

```
ISolrOperations<Something> solr = ...
using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"test.pdf")) {
    var response = solr.Extract(new ExtractParameters(file, "some_document_id") {
        ExtractOnly = true,
        ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
    });
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

Set `ExtractOnly` to false to index the content, and use `Fields` to set additional field values (i.e. an id field, etc.).